# Is there a simple way to empty my textbox after propertychanged in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, win-universal-app

**The setup:** I have a Windows 10 Universal app where I add a Task to my ObservableCollection when I click a button. I use relaycommands to call my Add method.

**The problem:** My TextBox doesn't sync even after I set the Task to empty. Or rather, the Text Property is empty, but the last entered text remains. I have tried to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and added `OnPropertyChanged();` after setting `Task="";` to no effect.
[image]

**My Add Method**

```
public async void AddTask()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Task))
    {
        Tasks.Add(new Task(Task));
        Task = "";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Write something first.");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

**My Xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextInput"
PlaceholderText="Enter your task here."
HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
TextWrapping="Wrap" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
Height="Auto"
MinHeight="200"
MaxHeight="400"
Width="Auto"
MinWidth="100"
MaxWidth="600"
FontSize="40"
Text="{Binding Task, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

If possible, I want to achieve this as simple as possible without using any codebehind.

Please write if you need further information or clarification. I will respond as swiftly as possible.

Comment: Does your task property implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Whoops. No it didn't. I thought it was ok to add it in my Add method. Now that I added it in my setter for my Task, it worked. Thanks! If you'll write your reply as an answer, I'll give you a check.

Comment: Don't use `async void`, you can't handle exceptions with it and any exception that occurs will crash the app. Use `async Task` instead. `async void` should only be used with async eventhandlers calls

Comment: @Tseng Thanks for the tip. New at this. When I change void to Task, I get a "Task" has the wrong return type. But I don't need any value returned. What do I do in such a case? Btw, changed my own Task to NextAction, as I can see this doesn't play well because of the already built in Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your Task property should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the UI that you reset Task to an empty string. Without INPC, the UI doesn't get updated.